# Relation between HPSA (Server Automation) and HPOO (Operation Orchestration)

Tags: hpsa

My question is simple, I only would like to understand how these two HP tools work together.
I have read some documentation but still unable to figure out if these tools are complementary or they can work together and in which cases

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

HP Server Automation is an Configuration Management Tool just like chef, ansible. It has inbuild capabilities of server provisioning, Patching and a lot more.

However HP Operation Orchestration is an orchestrator tool which has features of drag and drop operations.

Since in SA most of the things you can develop for maintaining your infrastructure you can use OO to automate all the things which is being done in SA.

For more reference please go through https://docs.microfocus.com/ for your understanding. You can ping me in case you have any other doubts around it.

Apparently the product has changed to Microfocus SA and OO. The products are no longer with HP.